# How can I get particular state of a contract through web3.js?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js

I deploy a simple token contract "MetaCoin through web3.js as follows:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || 'http://localhost:8545');
const abi = [...];
var MetaCoin = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, "0x77e82a433403f2d3273f391414b1eafe7e792624");
```

I can call a function 'getBalance()' of the contract and get the result like this:

```
MetaCoin.methods.getBalance("0x77e82a433403f2d3273f391414b1eafe7e792624").call().then(function(result){ console.log(result); });
```

But how can I call a state like 'address public creator' defined in the contract?

Answer (score 1):

When setting variables to public it automatically creates a getter method that can be used to query the variable.

```
contract Foo {
    uint public bar;
}
```

=>

```
myContractInstance.bar.call().then(function(result){ console.log(result); });
```

Comment: I know. In my contract, I define:
  `contract MetaCoin {
    address public creator;
  }`
then I call:
  `MetaCoin.creator.call().then(function(result){ console.log(result); });`
I get error: 
  **TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`**

Comment: past in the abi

Comment: I am I have latest abi

Comment: But thank you, I find 
`MetaCoin.methods.creator().call().then(function(result){ console.log(result); });` will get the value